# Import to Excel does not work

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, visual-studio-lightswitch

**I am using the [Office Integration Pack](http://officeintegration.codeplex.com/documentation?FocusElement=Comment)**

After following instruction correctly I am still not able to get the Excel to Import working

My **Visual Studio Lightswitch 2011 application** is configured to host on IIS Server and use's **Easy Shell** (so its the default Shell provided by MS).

So far I have tried is calling the

```
OfficeIntegration.Excel.Import(
   this.States, 
    @"C:\Users\Mr_Mia_Gie\My Documents\ExcelSheet.xls", 
    "Sheet1", 
   "A1:C3");
```

on `_Execute event` of a button (the button does not live on  the Shell Command Bar)

The exception I get back is **"Object variable or With block variable not set."**

Any solution or suggestion will be highly appreciated

Cheers

Comment: The error message itself suggests you have an unhandled null reference in there somewhere.  Check the status of the OfficeIntegration object, make sure it doesn't need to be initialized somewhere. Same with the Excel sub-class/namespace? of it.  Also, check this.States.  Perhaps your collection needs to be initialized first?

Comment: @Nevyn thank you, the error is thrown by the line of code shown in question. I am already using Office Integration Pack for Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011

Comment: Rather un-helpful.  What is the status of `this.States` at that line of code?  Is it null? Initialized but empty? You haven't said.  Also, are you certain that it is of the correct Type.  The documentation states that whatever that is either needs to be, or implement `IVisualCollection`.  These are the kinds of things to check and verify at this stage.  Also, double check the path you are providing.  Sometimes its the simplest things that get missed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The office integration Pack is for Visual Studio LightSwitch windows application and does work for application that are hosted on IIS hence the below code throws exception

```
OfficeIntegration.Excel.Import(
   this.States, 
    @"C:\Users\Mr_Mia_Gie\My Documents\ExcelSheet.xls", 
    "Sheet1", 
   "A1:C3");
```

The link show that the extension does not support LS WebBrowser application http://officeintegration.codeplex.com/discussions/374585

Also the extension Import data from Excel does work for IIS hosted LS application that runs in webbrowser

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Nevyn (& I'd vote up his answer, but it's embedded in the question as an *edit* so I can't).

As Nevyn has pointed out, there are really only three objects in that particular line of code that can be causing a *null exception*:

- the *OfficeIntegration* object
- the *OfficeIntegration.Excel* object
- or, the *this.States* collection (unlikely though)

As was also pointed out for you, it's most likely that one of those objects isn't correctly initialised. You need to check what the value of those three objects are by putting a break point on that line & checking what their values actually are at that point.

You could also put a guard clause in your code (just above that line):

***if (OfficeIntegration == null) || (OfficeIntegration.Excel == null) return;***

It won't neccesarily "fix" the problem, but it will stop the null exception from occuring (but this shouldn't be a problem in an *Execute* method). But it's good programing practice to put a guard clause **any time** you're referencing an object whose value could be null.

Failing that, the only other advice any of us can give you is to post a question in the questions section of the gallery page, where you downloaded the extension from. The autor of the extension should be able to help you.

Comment: thank you the reply but the office integration extension does support LS application that are hosted on IIS and run in webbrowser hence the weird error message. +1 because I agree with the logical explanation given by you

Answer (score 0):

Is this a web application, if so I dont think it supports it. It requires an extenstion. I dug up an article for you, try it out:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/04/13/how-to-import-data-from-excel.aspx

Comment: Thank you Michael, I am using the extension called Office Integration Pack and the error is thrown from it with the line of code shown in my question

Comment: Michael, if it was a matter of the extension not being supported in a wqeb application, you'd get a security exception, not a null exception.